# Using karma-systemjs produces 404 for dependencies

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, systemjs

I'm setting up unit tests on my app. My basic test spec, `project.spec.ts`, looks like

```
import {Project} from './project';

describe('Project', () => {
    let p = new Project('New project');

    it('should have the name given in the constructor', () => {
        expect(p.name).toBe('New project');
    });
});
```

`Project` is the name of the class that I am testing, and it is defined in the file `app/entities/project.ts` (i.e. in the same folder).

However, karma produces an 404 error whenever the test spec tries to import another file:

```
01 03 2016 17:21:04.955:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/app/entities/project
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading C:/Dev/mps/app/entities/project
        Error loading C:/Dev/mps/app/entities/project as "./project" from C:/Dev/mps/app/entities/project.spec.js
```

It looks like the compiled file `project.spec.js` is loaded correctly, but the file project.js fails to load. Also, I can't understand where the prefix `/base/` in `/base/app/entities/project` comes from.

A similar case is described [here](https://github.com/rolaveric/karma-systemjs/issues/58). However, the proposed solution does not work for me. Neither of the following import variations work:

```
let Project = require('./project');
let Project = System.import('./project'); // produces "404: /project" instead
let Project = require('./project.js');
let Project = System.import('./project.js');
```

My configs are:

*karma.conf.js*

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    plugins: ['karma-systemjs', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher'],
    frameworks: ['systemjs', 'jasmine'],
    systemjs: {
        configFile: 'system.conf.js'
    },
    files: [
      'app/entities/project.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [ ],
    preprocessors: { },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

*system.conf.js*

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        'traceur': 'node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
        'system-polyfills': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'es6-module-loader': 'node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js'
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using `.js` extension in your import statement thus you need either to add .js in import statements or to set `defaultJSExtensions: true` in your System.config (careful it will be deprecated in the future).
Regarding the `base` prefix, it is configured in karma-systemjs https://github.com/rolaveric/karma-systemjs/blob/master/lib/adapter.js#L109.
That prefix is used because Karma serves files under the /base directory.

Comment: @FidanHakaj I added `defaultJSExtensions: true`, but this still leads to the 404 error, albeit citing the .js file: `404: /base/app/entities/project.js` . As for the prefix, the link that you provided implies that I can override it by setting `baseURL` in the config of SystemJS? I tried adding `baseURL` to `system.conf.js` and to `systemjs` of `karma.conf.js´, but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Referenced files must be provided to SystemJS. This can be done with the parameter `systemjs.serveFiles` in `karma.conf.js`:

```
systemjs: {
  serveFiles: [
    'app/entities/project.js'
  ]
}
```

A nicer way is to use globs to configure this parameter just once:

```
systemjs: {
  serveFiles: [
    'node_modules/**/*.js',
    'app/**/*.js'
  ]
}
```